# Solr Filter query with NOT an AND operator

Tags: solr

I'm working on a solr query similar to the following:

((Author_Type:"Corporate" AND (Social_Media_Type_Source:"Retweet" OR Social_Media_Type_Source:"Comment")) OR NOT Author_Type:Corporate)
When running this, no results are returned. I am looking for is to pull the record,only if author_type matches Corporate and then Social_media_type_source is (retweet OR comment) or if author_type is not Corporate include it in the results.

I have seen similar example which is poster here but its seems not working on me.I am using solr4.10.1

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this isn't obsolete in Solr 4.x, but your problem may be in thinking that NOT can be a unary operator.

From the [Lucene/Solr 3.5 docs](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/queryparsersyntax.html#NOT):

> Note: The NOT operator cannot be used with just one term. For example,
>   the following search will return no results:
>
> NOT "jakarta apache"

You might be able to express the same thing by taking advantage of the fact that *:* will return all documents. Thus something like this might work:

> (Author_Type:"Corporate" AND (Social_Media_Type_Source:"Retweet" OR
>   Social_Media_Type_Source:"Comment")) OR (*:* NOT
>   Author_Type:Corporate)